# Creating pie chart from multiple variables

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, pie-chart

I'm using *iReport 5.1.0* and I have a report which compares different answers from different users to a unique question.

Now I have created 4 different variable for 4 possible answers and their count amongst users and this variable work all right! But I don't know how to create pie chart between these 4 variable. I've inserted pie chart and added multiple series and each with one of the variables. But the result is wrong. What should I do?
Here's my xml version of report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="r1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6c0b56f1-9c36-4a0d-8978-74e7c2279a3d">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="26"/>
    <parameter name="phaseid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="qformid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="groupid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="userid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="version" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{revision}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select
       phase."name" AS phasename,
       phase."id" AS phaseid,
       qform."title" AS ftitle,
       qform."id" AS fid,
       qform."phaseid" as phaseid,
       aform."id" as aId,
       aform."revision" as revision,
       aform."qformid" as aqid,
       aform."creator" as creator,
       users."id" as uid,
       user2group."groupid" as groupid,
       users."name" as name,
       users."family" as family,
       answer.*,
       master.*,
       CASE
         WHEN parent IS NULL THEN
    qnumber*1000
         ELSE
    (SELECT qnumber FROM question AS detail WHERE detail.id=master.parent)*1000+qnumber
         END AS test


FROM "public"."aform" aform
     INNER JOIN "public"."answer"answer ON aform."id" = answer."aformid"
     INNER JOIN "public"."qform"qform ON aform."qformid" = qform."id"
     INNER JOIN "public"."phase" phase ON qform."phaseid" = phase."id"
     INNER JOIN "public"."users" users ON  users."id" = aform."creator"
     INNER JOIN "public"."question" master ON qform."id" = master."qformid"
     INNER JOIN "public"."user2group" user2group ON user2group."userid" = aform."creator"
     AND master."id" = answer."questionid"

ORDER BY phase.id,qform.id,revision,test,users.id]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="phasename" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phaseid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ftitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="aid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="revision" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="aqid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="creator" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="uid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="groupid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="family" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="yes" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="no" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="incomplete" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="neednot" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="reference" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="questionid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="aformid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="score" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="totalscore" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ratio" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="qformid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="parent" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="haschild" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="qnumber" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="hd" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="test" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="yesCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="test" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{yes}.equals( "T" ) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="noCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="test" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{no}.equals( "T" ) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="incompleteCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="test" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{incomplete}.equals( "T" ) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="noneedCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="test" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{neednot}.equals( "T" ) ? 1 : 0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <filterExpression><![CDATA[($P{qformid}!=null ? $F{fid}==$P{qformid} : ($P{phaseid}!=null ? $F{phaseid}==$P{phaseid} : true))
&&
($P{userid}!=null ? $F{uid}==$P{userid} : ($P{groupid}!=null ? $F{groupid}==$P{groupid} : true))
&&
(($P{version}!=null && !$P{version}.isEmpty()) ? $F{revision}==$P{version} : true)]]></filterExpression>
    <group name="fid">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{fid}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="68">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="77fb3930-5fe4-45d7-b51f-144da054c7a5" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="36" width="555" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="15" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ftitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="f2b71224-d0d7-483e-982a-50d51bb50b27" x="4" y="4" width="545" height="32"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new String("فاز:") + $F{phasename}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="revision">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{revision}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="614bdc70-dfef-4bb1-8100-650adf351e03" x="10" y="13" width="545" height="17"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["نسخه"+" "+$F{revision}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="test">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{test}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="100">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement uuid="18474e1d-d1a5-43fb-a97d-07e31fa74d2a" x="0" y="64" width="555" height="36">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                    </box>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="2442e18d-0e22-4063-988a-63bda798b50a" x="352" y="0" width="46" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[بله]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="ac95d72c-f557-4804-97c2-bf3e091c6f68" x="307" y="0" width="44" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[ناقص]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="a3f4991b-5044-46f7-9fdc-36016ffa7635" x="264" y="0" width="42" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[خیر]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement uuid="1319056e-82eb-426b-9e1d-f776722d4098" x="398" y="0" width="1" height="36"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="70d428b7-7cff-49f0-9672-a2c6d58ab1d5" x="203" y="0" width="61" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[نیاز نیست]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="d1ca0268-f0de-4f71-a77a-b101925e663d" x="0" y="0" width="203" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[مرجع پاسخ]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement uuid="590b403c-118c-4ec7-b532-8520e1f553a0" x="351" y="0" width="1" height="36"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement uuid="502d54b2-0f0f-4c6a-8fda-b3b8b932d273" x="306" y="0" width="1" height="36"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement uuid="26cebb69-628c-4bf5-94f4-5e338a3a3fd0" x="265" y="0" width="1" height="36"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement uuid="0ed0e936-9529-4744-a457-f2570b48868d" x="203" y="0" width="1" height="36"/>
                        <graphicElement>
                            <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                        </graphicElement>
                    </line>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement uuid="d323c494-00e0-436a-8bd2-0645f1604693" x="398" y="0" width="157" height="36"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[تهیه کننده]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement uuid="1df8e3d2-5ab8-4a1f-84f6-6789fc7355bc" x="0" y="19" width="555" height="30"/>
                </rectangle>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="f570ba26-7cf0-4214-9d66-03b291a5c668" x="520" y="19" width="29" height="29"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}==null ? $F{qnumber} : $F{qnumber} +"-"+ (int)($F{test}/1000)]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="495924cd-ac2c-4bff-b216-c23ef5588613" x="490" y="19" width="32" height="29">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}==null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{hd}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="674bd7f9-5b84-40b8-9062-d58088b13291" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="37" y="18" width="424" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="13" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="b988a082-e453-4866-9d99-9b4267877f25" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="37" y="19" width="445" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}==null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="13" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="cdc087dd-7633-4b96-be67-246edfa85f6c" x="0" y="19" width="36" height="29">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}==null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ratio}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="49e9f2db-a838-49fc-8021-cc5bdd924303" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="520" y="19" width="1" height="30"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="681e4508-5703-4f4c-9ad2-aba9f4f7e340" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="488" y="19" width="1" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}==null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="e2a4436d-f2ce-4422-837c-e35aa5b3da9c" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="36" y="19" width="1" height="30"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="77a02989-c90a-4e28-924a-1f066920cf22" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="461" y="19" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{parent}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="100">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement uuid="ef148a3a-d76c-42f8-8d37-d40571742d37" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="100">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="372012f2-9875-445d-b7ca-2ebf7e27ee8f" x="399" y="0" width="156" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[مجموع]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="5c956c41-6e8d-4daf-860e-105521bbabea" x="399" y="0" width="1" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="f9fe1bce-bb93-4b47-a4ef-ccced95a7718" x="351" y="0" width="46" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{yesCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="c5e56984-2e59-4c2f-be31-77c882a92164" x="307" y="0" width="44" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{incompleteCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="dd1100d6-6a21-42d6-a1ad-9854132719c6" x="265" y="0" width="42" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{noCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="eeaa84d4-467f-44fc-aabd-73f8f16f4819" x="204" y="0" width="61" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{noneedCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="547c6e74-6d3c-4fe7-936f-32b79f52ee92" x="204" y="0" width="1" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                </line>
                <pieChart>
                    <chart isShowLegend="false">
                        <reportElement uuid="6712572f-5729-4a1b-ab4b-f984d90fcdfa" x="3" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <pieDataset>
                        <pieSeries>
                            <keyExpression><![CDATA[$V{yesCount}]]></keyExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{yesCount}]]></valueExpression>
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA["آری"]]></labelExpression>
                        </pieSeries>
                        <pieSeries>
                            <keyExpression><![CDATA[$V{noCount}]]></keyExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{noCount}]]></valueExpression>
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA["نه"]]></labelExpression>
                        </pieSeries>
                        <pieSeries>
                            <keyExpression><![CDATA[$V{incompleteCount}]]></keyExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{incompleteCount}]]></valueExpression>
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA["ناقص"]]></labelExpression>
                        </pieSeries>
                        <pieSeries>
                            <keyExpression><![CDATA[$V{noneedCount}]]></keyExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{noneedCount}]]></valueExpression>
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA["نیازی نیست"]]></labelExpression>
                        </pieSeries>
                    </pieDataset>
                    <piePlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                    </piePlot>
                </pieChart>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <rectangle radius="10">
                <reportElement uuid="a1bdf7e1-5da2-42c7-9062-945fc00bcf63" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="33" forecolor="#0033CC" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c0192e0b-b7eb-4fea-a925-8e1d60fa584e" x="42" y="10" width="478" height="31"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[پروژه جامع گمرک نوین]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame">
                <reportElement uuid="f3451058-4800-450f-b8ec-25b660a3b6e5" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="10" y="13" width="28" height="28"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["./f.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape">
                <reportElement uuid="732d3c9a-5e7a-4a67-9334-87c31cbf42bd" x="518" y="10" width="33" height="33"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["./g.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="58ab58b5-7ee4-4981-9af1-f768b6f8d3c6" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="2.0" lineColor="#0033CC"/>
                </box>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="35e4246b-e5b6-49e7-a1c7-c706ef15b88a" x="400" y="0" width="155" height="30"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{uid}.intValue()==$F{creator}.intValue() ? ($F{name}+" "+$F{family}) : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="a786eae2-eec2-4733-9b78-10235a8394dd" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="399" y="0" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                    <reportElement uuid="1151a318-559c-4d23-ae9d-0e79818fa511" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="361" y="6" width="29" height="18">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{yes}.equals( "T" ) ? "checked.jpg" : "unchecked.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="b1c6cc0a-a9b9-45dc-ab67-22666ebfe18f" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="352" y="0" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                    <reportElement uuid="7d94a3a2-76a1-4862-801d-83139eae841e" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="316" y="7" width="26" height="18">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{incomplete}.equals( "T" ) ? "checked.jpg" : "unchecked.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="65b88f44-f97b-464b-9483-8c8d8d2867e4" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="306" y="0" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                    <reportElement uuid="70e6f393-3ab9-4b71-9d90-9dfb825fda53" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="273" y="8" width="26" height="18">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{no}.equals( "T" ) ? "checked.jpg" : "unchecked.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="c69b4574-c05a-49a3-a46e-8b692d516187" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="265" y="0" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <image hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                    <reportElement uuid="603564a4-bd04-4d2d-8552-911052e2f318" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="220" y="7" width="34" height="18">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </box>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{neednot}.equals( "T" ) ? "checked.jpg" : "unchecked.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="97e6ddaf-6519-4162-bab8-fc83636c535a" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="204" y="0" width="1" height="30">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{haschild}.equalsIgnoreCase("n")]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#0000FF"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="6a2507ec-b223-40bf-8a2f-51f0378accec" x="0" y="0" width="203" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{reference} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Serif" size="13"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reference}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="24">
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="9f246d66-8613-4740-90c8-d119f291d693" x="449" y="0" width="106" height="24" forecolor="#0033CC"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="cb906951-ced3-47ee-b33e-461280a8b5fd" x="11" y="4" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#0033CC"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="a53bbbc6-4ce5-4b4a-b6bd-3a55c4757a82" x="53" y="4" width="58" height="20" forecolor="#0033CC"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["صفحه"+" " +$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" از"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

and a screen shot from report:
[image]

as you can see pie should be all green but ....

Comment: Can you post *jrxml* file and the screenshots of generated report: TO-BE and AS-IS?

Comment: I edited question to contain xml and a screenshot.

Comment: what do you want to show in pie chart ?please elaborate

Comment: As you can see in xml file, I have 4 possible answers which are in variable parts. (yesCount, noCount, incompleteCount and noneedCount). I want to create a pie chart spread between these values.